# SQLite in C# throws "InvalidCastException" using .GetBytes

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to access a column of Blob's in an SQLite DB which will eventually be pointers to a record on a file or in memory.  I'm trying to use the .GetBytes method in SQLite to get an array of bytes that will represent my data.  I keep getting an InvalidCastException while using this method.  Everything seems to be in place and the program compiles just fine, but during runtime this exception keeps getting thrown.  I've looked around for answers and everything seems to agree with the code I have so I am at a loss here, and unfortunately I can't find any good documentation for SQLite in C#.  Code is as follows

```
  public byte[] Output()
    {
        byte[] temp = null;
        int col = Columns + 1;
        if(read.Read())
        {
            read.GetBytes(col, 0, temp, 0, 2048); //exception is thrown here
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

I've been able to read other columns in the DB that are ints and texts, but for some reason can't seem to get the blobs right.

EDIT: new info, Here is the stack trace from the exception:

```
     StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(Int32 i, DbType typ)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.GetBytes(Int32 i, Int64 fieldOffset, Byte[] buffer, Int32 bufferoffset, Int32 length)
   at SQLiteSort.Sort.Output() in C:\Users\cjones\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Sort.cs:line 192
   at SQLiteSort.Sort.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\cjones\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Sort.cs:line 72
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

InnerException:

The exception seems to be thrown by SQLiteDataReader.VerifyType(), this is looking at the column being used for a DbType.Binary type and throws an exception if the column is not a DbType.Binary, DbType.String, or DbType.Guid.  I've checked the table over and over and it still shows the column type as a blob.

Comment: What is the message in the exception?  For instance, `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.`?

Comment: System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Specified cast is not valid.
  Source=System.Data.SQLite

Comment: Okay, better question, if you add `if (read.IsDBNull(col)) return null;` before the read, does it solve the problem?

Comment: Nope, it does not.  I'm able to look at the read object in VS and can see that the column is populated with bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally fixed the problem by using parameter's and setting my Blob to DbType.Binary.  Not sure why this is so different from what I was doing before but everything is working as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it throws an `InvalidCastException` certainly seems wrong, but your code *is* broken - `temp` will be null, which surely it shouldn't be. You're not providing anywhere for the data to be read to.

You're *also* not taking note of the return value of `GetBytes`, which I'd expect you to...

EDIT: Just to check... you *are* trying to read from an appropriate column, right? `InvalidCastException` would be somewhat appropriate if you were trying to call `GetBytes` on (say) an integer column.

Comment: I've tried setting temp to a new object    byte[] temp = new byte[2048] , but still get the same exception.  I realize GetBytes returns a value but I have no use for it that I can think of.

Comment: @ChrisJones: Why on earth would you *not* want to know how much data has been read? And which line is throwing the exception? If you could produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would really help.

Comment: Yes I am trying to read the correct column, I just checked to make sure that wasn't the problem.

Comment: It seemed fishy to me that the SQLite driver itself would throw a cast exception (particularly for reading binary data), given that it doesn't really enforce types to begin with. So, I poked my head into the source code, and discovered that ReadBytes *will* explicitly throw an exception if the affinity of the column is not "BLOB", (otherwise known as none). Something is definitely wrong either with the table definition, or the column being referenced.

Comment: @mootinator - the table definition is definitely "BLOB" and I'm trying to access that column.  I can access it by using .ToString()  and it outputs System.Byte[] so I know most definitely that it is a byte[] and it is accessible, just confused as to why it won't let me access it as a byte[].  Is there maybe something wrong with the .GetBytes() method?

Comment: Actually the issue querying BLOB fields remains. As said here in the comment by @ChrisJones, one can access a binary BLOB fields using index property and explicit cast `(byte[])reader[0]`. The GetBytes method throws InvalidCastException and GetValue returns the bytes as a string. GetBytes should throw NotSupported, instead of just-cast-some-bytes-to-(encoded-)chars and say-they-are-a-string. Or someone implements it...

Comment: For the record: It was likely an issue in the tool SQLiteStudio I've used to predesign the database or a conflict between tool's SQLite 3.7.x and my program's 3.8.x. It "looked" correct because the managed library finally returned the correct bytes, however querying by the column didn't work and the strange exception was thrown. Populating the database by the program itself (and so the same managed/native sqlite version) solved the conflict. GetBytes works just fine ;)