# Querying SQLite by BLOB column not possible?

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to query a SQLite table by a blob column which is a SHA256 hash.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Articles (HASH BLOB(32) PRIMARY KEY, Article TEXT)
```

A query like this doesn't return anything:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE HASH = ?
-- the parameter is bound using sqlite3_bind_blob, not to use literals
```

I made this little Program in C# which creates the table and also inserts a row to try.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

// using lib;

public class Program {

    static int Main(string[] args) 
    {
        // Console.WriteLine(sqlite3.LibVersion);

        byte[] qHash;
        string qArticle = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

        using (var hashAlgorithm = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider ()) {

            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(qArticle);

            qHash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(bytes);
        }

        var con = new SQLiteConnection ("Data Source=test.sqlite");
        con.Open();

        try {
            var create = new SQLiteCommand ("CREATE TABLE Articles (HASH BLOB(32) PRIMARY KEY, Article TEXT)", con);
            create.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var insert = new SQLiteCommand ("INSERT INTO Articles (HASH, Article) VALUES (?, ?); SELECT last_insert_rowid();", con);

            var insertParam0 = new SQLiteParameter(DbType.Binary);
            insertParam0.Value = qHash;
            insert.Parameters.Add(insertParam0);

            var insertParam1 = new SQLiteParameter(DbType.String);
            insertParam1.Value = qArticle;
            insert.Parameters.Add(insertParam1);

            object insert_result = insert.ExecuteScalar();
            var insert_rowid = (long)insert_result; 

        } catch { } // silently fail if exists usually

        var query = new SQLiteCommand ("SELECT * FROM Articles WHERE HASH = @hash", con);

        var param = new SQLiteParameter ("@hash", DbType.Binary);
        param.Value = qHash;
        query.Parameters.Add(param);

        using (SQLiteDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader()) {

            while (reader.NextResult()) {
                var hash = new byte[32];
                long hashLen = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, hash, 0, 32);

                string article = reader.GetString(1);

                Console.WriteLine("HASH: {0}; Article: {1}", 
                    hash == null ? null : BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", ""), 
                    article
                );
            }

        }
        con.Close();

        return 0;
    }

}
```

However the `reader` doesn't have a result. Is querying a BLOB column not supported at all?
Is something else bugging me?

Comment: Querying blobs should work just fine ([example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cca32/1) with blob literals). Did the insert work, i.e., does the DB contain that row?

Comment: Sure, the row exists; I don't want to use literals (which also don't work...), because of hex conversion, string concats, escaping etc.

Comment: HELL it works with `reader.Read` instead of `.NextResult` whyever. Should I close this Q?

Comment: @metadings Post that as an answer and accept it when you're allowed to. It'll help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was solved by discovering that `Read` is used in a

```
while (reader.Read()) { }
```

loop, whereas `NextResult` is used in a

```
do { } while (reader.NextResult());
```

loop.

However the inital problem was, that in my real project I created the database using SQLiteStudio (SQLite 3.7.16.1) in the BLOB Hex Editor; that confused the `System.Data.SQLite` library (using SQLite 3.8.2).

Now by creating the database using the program itself solved also the initial issue

- [SQLite in C# throws “InvalidCastException” using .GetBytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10746237/1352471)
  which I worked around with `(byte[])reader[0]` and also returned the correct bytes, but was not being qualified in a SELECT, neither with a parameter nor with a literal

So said, don't mix SQLite versions, not even to quickly try something. I tried so hard, I've even started a UnmanagedLibrary with DllImport bindings for sqlite3_*, just to discover that this was not the problem.